# What is the purpose of GRE in IPSec or IPSec in GRE?

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec

This is a general knowledge question I can't wrap my head around.  I've set up many of IPSec tunnels throughout the years both for site-to-site and to direct internet traffic through a tunnel.

I just learned of "route based IPSec" and I've always done it policy based where you set the left and right subnets.  These subnets explicitly appear in the IPSec SA.

The more I read about IPSec I've seen blog posts about IPSec over GRE and GRE over IPSec.  What is the added benefit of the overhead of an additional header?  I've always just routed traffic through tunnels without this and everything was fine

Comment: I think you may hit a better target audience at http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: IPSec can only be used to encrypt unicast packets. GRE is an encapsulation protocol which can transport unicast, multicast, broadcast or even non-IP protocols. So you might want to use a GRE tunnel to form routing neighborships between the main and branch offices and also use IPSec to secure the tunnel so that is encrypted and authenticated.

Comment: @MarkoPolo - I was under the assumption that the original IP header was "stuffed" into the encrypted payload of the IPSec packet, just like GRE does but GRE is obviously unencrpypted.  Under this assumption GRE would make things redundant.

Comment: IPSec Tunnel mode will indeed encrypt the entire IP packet including the original IP address. The original packet is encapsulated into a new set of headers. IPSec Transport mode does not encrypt the original IP header information. In either mode, IPSec can still only be used to encrypt Unicast packets which is why GRE is still useful - typically, you tunnel your packets within GRE and then encrypt the GRE packet with IPSEC.

Comment: @MarkoPolo - Why wold IPSec care though?  Let's say the original packet  has a src of 192.168.1.100 and a DST of 224.0.0.50 (some multicast address).  How is this any different than a src of 192.168.1.100 and a dst of 10.5.50.50?  The packet is fundamentally the same or am I missing something?

Comment: If you think of it at the IP level sure, a unicast packet is structured very similarly to a Multicast packet. However, IPSec SA's are point-to-point, there isn't any way (at least in the RFC standard) for a single SA to be in use between multiple endpoints at the same time.

Comment: @MarkoPolo - Could one just use a "route based IPSec" where the left\right subnet are 0.0.0.0\0 and packets are pushed into the pseudo adapters throught something like PBR

Comment: A good use of GRE together with IPSec is the [DMVPN solution](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/ipsec-negotiation-ike-protocols/41940-dmvpn.html): The DMVPN solution uses Multipoint GRE (mGRE) and Next Hop Resolution Protocol (NHRP), with IPsec and some new enhancements, to solve the above problems in a scalable manner.

Comment: @MarkoPolo: sorry but `IPSec can only be used to encrypt unicast packets` is wrong. See e.g. [GETVPN](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4t/12_4t11/htgetvpn.html#wp1143907) and [VTI](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3t/12_3t14/feature/guide/gtIPSctm.html)

Comment: @jdoe: your comment about the 0.0.0.0/0 is more or less what VTI does, but not with PBR. It just encrypts everything you route to the Tunnel interface.

Comment: @hertitu You are correct that VTI's support Multicast traffic, however regular IPSec tunnels do not.